# Image Carousel SPFx webpart with video as a source

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, reactjs, carousel

I want to bind a video in carousel with source which is a hyperlink in the carousel.

I am able to bind images but not able to bind video as a source. How do I load videos with images?

```
<div style={ divStyle }>
  <div className={ styles.reactCarousel }>
    <Carousel dynamicHeight={ true } showThumbs = { false}  autoPlay = { true} >
      {
        this.state.items.map((imageList, key) => {
          return (<div>
            {/* <iframe src={imageList.Image? imageList.Image["Url"] : ''} width="560" height="315"></iframe>  */ }
            < video  src = { imageList.Image ? imageList.Image["Url"] : '' } > </video>
            {/* <img  src={imageList.Image? imageList.Image["Url"] : ''}  />  */ }
            <p className={ styles.legends } onClick = {() => { this._onClickItem(imageList.Title) }
        }> { imageList.Title } < /p>   
        < /div>)    
    })}
</Carousel>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? Or you can add video but it is not playing automatically?

Comment: its showing blank black if i use i frame it is coming but i have to render video image both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src={ imageList.Image ? imageList.Image["Url"] : '' } type="video/mp4">  
   Text if video is not loaded
</video>
```

where type is optional.

instead of:

```
<video src = { imageList.Image ? imageList.Image["Url"] : '' }> </video>
```

Comment: Thank you i will ry this and update you soon

Comment: its is working but its mandatory height and width can i give it default carosuel size

Comment: No it is not mandatory. You can give urs

Comment: Please mark this as answer if the answer helped solve your issue/requirement.